# fetching data based upon a multiple columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table apartments and the table structure looks like below

```
      id    |   apid   |   bhk   |   facing  | size  |  units
       1    |     2    |    2    |    east   |  1200 |   20
       2    |     2    |    2    |    east   |  1500 |   40
       3    |     2    |    2    |    west   |  1300 |   30
       4    |     2    |    2    |   north   |  1400 |   10
       5    |     2    |    2    |   north   |  1500 |   30
       6    |     2    |    3    |    east   |  1100 |   25
       7    |     2    |    3    |    north  |  1000 |   40
       8    |     3    |    2    |     west  |  850  |   15
       9    |     3    |    2    |    south  |  970  |   20
       10   |     3    |    3    |    south  |  1200 |   35
```

I have to write a query such that I have to get the output as apid=2, bhk=2, facing=east, sum(units)=60 and apid=2, bhk=2, facing=north, sum(units)=40

Comment: What have you tries so far?

Answer (score 0):

query 1:

```
select apid,bhk,facing,sum(units) from apartments where apid=2,bhk=2,facing = 'east'
```

query 2

```
select apid,bhk,facing,sum(units) from apartments where apid=2,bhk=2,facing = 'north'
```

Final Query:

```
    select apid,bhk,facing,sum(units) from apartments where apid=2,bhk=2,facing = 'east'

UNION 

    select apid,bhk,facing,sum(units) from apartments where apid=2,bhk=2,facing = 'north'
```